# Set default value in select when the ng-model is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to set a default state to select when my ng-model is null. Basically I want to set it to 'None' if the model is empty. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
<select ng-init="item.carType | item.carType='none'" ng-model="item.carType">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto</option>                      
</select>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select ng-init="item.carType = item.carType || 'none'" ng-model="item.carType">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto</option>                      
</select>
```

That said, [per the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), this is probably a misuse of `ngInit`. The proper way to do this would be to initialize your model with sane values in the controller (or service, if that's where it came from).

Comment: What does this mean `item.carType = item.carType` ?

Comment: This will assign `item.carType` to itself if it is a "truthy" value, otherwise it will assign the string 'none' to `item.carType`. So, if `item.carType` already has a value, nothing changes, otherwise — thanks to the `||` — it will be assigned to the string value 'none'.

Comment: Don't do this. This messes with validation. If you have a `required` flag, setting the default to `'none'` will make this value 'set' and it won't fire the `required` error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is discouraged. In my case, I'm using it in a nested scope created by `ng-if` which can't be modified by my controller's scope.

Answer (score 3):

H i ,

My thoughts are it is best to do this in the app rather than the template.

```
  if(typeof $scope.item.carType==="undefined") {
     $scope.item.carType="none";
  }
```

or simply setting the value

```
$scope.item.carType="none";
```

before it is updated with whatever you are using to set the value : -

```
$scope.item.carType="none";
$scope.item.carType=someasyncfunctionthatmighttakeawhileandthetemplateisrenderedbeforeitarrives();
```

Comment: nice big function name

Answer (score 3):

You can solve using a value in ng-init

```
<select ng-init="item.carType='none'" ng-model="item.carType">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto</option>                      
</select>
```

Comment: cardeol this is suited when the form is empty else if item.carType already has a value it still defaults to none.

Comment: null counts as an actual value , maybe the OP means undefined ?

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest you to do is this.
Make a function in your controller and check if `$scope.item.carType == undefined` assign a default value.

```
$scope.setDefaultValueForCarType = function () {
      if($scope.item.carType == undefined) {
          $scope.item.carType = "none";
      }
}
```

This will work too.

```
<select ng-init="item.carType='none'" ng-model="item.carType">
```

Comment: thank you for reply was thinking about this, but wanted to try out the ng-init way.

Answer (score 2):

Often happens that your `ng-model="item.carType"` doesn't match any of the select option keys because of the wrong case.

For example: `item.cartType` is `"Manual"` but in the options you have an option `<option value="manual">Manual</option>` in this case it won't work and in the console output you'll see something like this: `<option value="? string:Manual ?"></option>`

So, either correct your data model or your select option value:
`<option value="Manual">Manual</option>`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is undefined.

If the value is undefined do you need a value to go to the database when 'none' is selected?

If sending an empty is acceptable you may consider the following:

```
<select ng-model="item.carType">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto</option>                      
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/fPpW9/)

This allows you to pass in a value as well and use the same form for edits and new records.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rob Sedgwick idea, in a pinch deadline I'm not using `$scope` so with controller as syntax.

```
loadStates(); //this calls my function for my code

// this is based on what Rob S. is doing with $scope    
if(typeof vm.scriptQuestion.statecode ==="undefined") {
    console.log('in');
    vm.scriptQuestion.statecode = "AA";  // "AA" happens to be the value of the default name for All of my States that is then displaying "ALL" now when before it was blank
}
```

Here is my Select  ( yes, this is a garbage way of doing angular select boxes as ng-repeat is very limited for a select )

```
 <select id="States" ng-model="vm.scriptQuestion.statecode">
     <option ng-repeat="state in vm.states" value="{{state.StateCode}}">{{state.StateName}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made the following changes to your code and it should work now. I've removed the second part in `ng-init=""` and set the None option value to `undefined`.

```
<select ng-init="item.carType='none'" ng-model="item.carType">
    <option value=undefined>None</option>
    <option value="manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="auto">Auto</option>                      
</select>
```