# Enable/Disable button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, disabled-input

I have a table that has a checkbox. It has a select ALL javascript function and a select one  by one function. My html file looks like this for the delete button:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal" contenteditable="false" id="delbutton" ng-model="delbutton" ng-disabled="countChecked() == 0">Delete</span></button>
```

Select All Checkbox:

```
<th class="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select" id="checkAll" ng-model="selectAllRawSCP"/>
</th>
```

table details:

```
<tr ng-repeat=" item in rawSCAP | orderBy:sort">
   <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked" ng-model="item.checked"/>
    </td>
```

I used the code I saw in one of the answers here in stack overflow to disable the delete button if there is no checkbox checked. It looks like this:

```
$scope.countChecked = function(){
            var count = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.rawSCAP, function(value){
                if (value.checked) count++;
            });

            return count;
        }
```

But using this, my page returns an error which isTypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
[image: Error]

And also I need to enable delete button even if I used select all

Comment: could you please insert the plunker here ?

Comment: what is the value of $scope.rawSCAP in the loop

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, it cannot access the property **checked** of the rawSCAP itens. You have to guarantee rawSCAP itens checked property is not null before you try to use it in ng-model.

You could try to initialize it before with some value you want. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859898/2228536) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some conditions you need to follow to use the `<<ng-model>>.checked`, which is a **plain array can't be used for checkbox**, it must be an **`array of objects`**. Also please change your function to below.

```
  $scope.countChecked = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.rawSCAP, function(value) {
        value.checked = value.checked || 0;
      if (value.checked) count++;
    });

    return count;
  }
```

The main line which does the work is `value.checked = value.checked || 0;` Here if the `value.checked` is undefined, then the `0` will get assigned to `value.checked`, hence you won't get the error!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.rawSCAP = [{
    item: 1
  }, {
    item: 2
  }, {
    item: 3
  }, {
    item: 4
  }, {
    item: 5
  }, {
    item: 6
  }, {
    item: 7
  }];

  $scope.countChecked = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.rawSCAP, function(value) {
     value.checked = value.checked || 0;
      if (value.checked) count++;
    });

    return count;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal" contenteditable="false" id="delbutton" ng-model="delbutton" ng-disabled="countChecked() == 0">Delete</button>
  <table>
    <th class="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="select" id="checkAll" ng-model="selectAllRawSCP" />
    </th>
    <tr ng-repeat=" item in rawSCAP | orderBy:sort">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="checked" ng-model="item.checked" />{{item.item}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: @bleykFaust Does this answer help you?